# rails duplication code user_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, code-climate

I have a master admin who can create two different admins [property, content_contributor].
In the master admin's require params I have this

```
 class MasterAdmins::ContentContributorsController < MasterAdmins::MainController
....
params.require(:content_contributor).permit(:user_id, user_attributes: [:id, :activation_token, :email, :encrypted_password, :authentication_token, :sign_in_count]
```

and in master admins property I have this

```
 class MasterAdmins::PropertyAdminsController < MasterAdmins::MainController
 .....
 params.require(:property_admin).permit(user_attributes: [:id, :activation_token, :email, :encrypted_password, :authentication_token, :sign_in_count]
```

I am getting duplicate found in code climate. How can I avoid the user attribute duplication?

Comment: make a controller and inherit from it..

Comment: for just one line params .require i need to create a controller?

Comment: will you try please, it should work,

Comment: Can you help me with coding? Do i need to to write a method in mainController and then call it inside the params?

Comment: check this.. https://github.com/argentum47/stekoverflu/blob/votes_and_ui/app/controllers/votes_controller.rb https://github.com/argentum47/stekoverflu/blob/votes_and_ui/app/controllers/answers_votes_controller.rb . only that, you will have the `def admin_params; params...` in one controller and then you can say `Admin.create(admins_param)` in either of your controller. make sure you don't call a private method by any object explicitly, even self.admin_params would be an error..

Comment: When pasting code into SO, please try to make it so that horizontal scrolling isn't needed.  I just can't read code that is one long line... by the time I scroll to the end, I forget what was at the beginning.